# reconocer caracteres especiales en typescript, por ejemplo: "\"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estimados tengo una consulta, me mandan una llave desde un servicio, por ejemplo:
\akdkKL*0
Debo utilizar dicha llave y devolver un valor, el problema es que no reconoce el caracter:"\"; esto lo hice enviando valores.Como puedo hacer para que reconozca y asi no tener problemas.

Comment: Podes mostrar el codigo que te genera problemas?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus aportes, ya lo pude resolver enviando con el siguiente formato:

```
String.raw`${variable_enviada}`
```

Asi envio el valor y reconoce todo caracter.